# Paint ArrayList of Shape Objects to Frame

Tags: java, interface, arraylist, drawable, draw

I'm having difficulty with drawing Shapes (Circle & Rectangle) into a Frame.

I have created both a Circle and a Rectangle Class that implements the Shape Interface. I have then created  DrawableCircle and DrawableRectangle Classes that extend the Circle and Rectangle Classes appropriately, and implement the Drawable Interface.

I am now trying to create a ShapesDriver Class which extends Frame and has within it the main method and paint(Graphics g) method. Within ShapesDriver I need to create an ArrayList of type Drawable. This ArrayList holds an instance of DrawableCircle and DrawableRectangle. In the paint method I have to iterate through the ArrayList and invoke the draw method for each shape.

This is where I am stuck...

Any help would be appreciated!

Shape Interface

```
public interface Shape {

    public double area();

}
```

Circle Class

```
 public class Circle implements Shape{

        private int radius;
        private double area;

        public Circle(int r){
            radius = r;

        }

        @Override
        public double area() {

            area = Math.PI * (radius * radius);
            return area;
        }

}
```

Rectangle Class

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape{

    double height;
    double width;
    double area;

    public Rectangle(double h, double w){
        height = h;
        width = w;
    }

    @Override
    public double area() {
        area = height * width;
        return area;
    }

}
```

Drawable Interface

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;

public interface DrawableInterface {

    public void setColor(Color c);
    public void setPosition(int x, int y);
    public void draw(Graphics g);

}
```

DrawableCircle

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class DrawableCircle extends Circle implements DrawableInterface{

    private Color col;
    private int posX;
    private int posY;

    public DrawableCircle(int r){
        super(r);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColor(Color c) {
        col = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
        posX = x;
        posY = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {

        g.setColor(col);
        g.drawOval(posX, posY, 15, 15);
    }



}
```

DrawableRectangle

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;


public class DrawableRectangle extends Rectangle implements DrawableInterface{

    private Color col;
    private int posX;
    private int posY;

    public DrawableRectangle(double h, double w){
        super(h, w);
    }

    @Override
    public void setColor(Color c) {
        col = c;
    }

    @Override
    public void setPosition(int x, int y) {
        posX = x;
        posY = y;
    }

    @Override
    public void draw(Graphics g) {

    g.setColor(col);
    g.drawRect(posX,posY,10,10);

    }

}
```

ShapesDriver

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Frame;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.event.WindowAdapter;
import java.awt.event.WindowEvent;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class ShapesDriver extends Frame {

static ArrayList<DrawableInterface> shapesArr = new ArrayList<DrawableInterface>();

    public ShapesDriver() {
        super("Shapes Object Array");
        setSize(400, 300);
        setLocation(200, 200);

        setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {


        DrawableCircle c = new DrawableCircle(500);
        c.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        c.setPosition(25, 25);

        DrawableRectangle r = new DrawableRectangle(100, 50);
        r.setColor(Color.RED);
        r.setPosition(75, 75);

        shapesArr.add(c);
        shapesArr.add(r);


 ShapesDriver shapeFrame = new ShapesDriver();

         shapeFrame.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void paint(Graphics g) {

        for (DrawableInterface s : shapesArr) {
            super.paint(g);

            s.draw(g);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`"This is where I am stuck..."` -- where are you stuck exactly?

Myself, I would:

- use a Swing GUI not an AWT GUI since Swing is much more powerful and flexible than AWT. There's almost never a need to create AWT GUI's.
- Your GUI class, ShapesDriver does nothing. It extends Frame, but you never create an instance of the ShapesDriver. Instead it has a main method where you create a separate Frame. In my GUI code, I'd create a true GUI class, that had instance fields and methods, and would be sure to create an instance of this class somewhere.
- In my GUI class I'd have my ArrayList of Shape and my drawing method, and would loop through the ArrayList within the drawing method, drawing each shape as I looped.
- Since I would favor using Swing, my GUI class would extend JPanel, and my drawing method would be a `paintComponent(Graphics g)` method. If you're required to use AWT, then you could instead use a Panel and draw in its `paint(Graphics g)` method.
- I'd then have a main method that creates the GUI, makes it visible, and does nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the response!
Yeah, given the specification I have been given, it looks like I'm stuck using a Frame as opposed to JFrame. I have some slight experience with JFrames, & no experience with awt Frames.

Comment: I'm not sure about what needs to go into the paint method, nor what steps I need to take to iterate through the ArrayList painting the objects contained within it?

Comment: @user2904978: I try to avoid spoonfeeding, so let's see your best attempt.

Comment: So instead of Frame shapeFrame = new Frame();

I ought to instead have something like ShapesDriver shapeFrame = new ShapesDriver();

Comment: @user2904978: yes, your main method will need to do that, to create and display an instance of ShapesDriver.

Comment: So I've made some small adjustments, but I still need some direction on how to implement the paint method. I think I have correctly added both a DrawableCircle and DrawableRectangle to the ArrayList, but I don't know how to iterate through that array & then paint the objects in it.

Comment: @user2904978: you surely know how to use a for loop to iterate through an array, right? I'd try that.

Comment: In the paint method I have to iterate through the ArrayList and then invoke the draw method for each shape.

Comment: I'm not sure what object type I need to be checking for...

for (*** ? *** s : shapesArr)

?

Comment: Your shapsArr List is a List of DrawableInterface, so that is the type you'll need to use in the for loop. Please look up how to use for loops for the details on how to use for loops, since this is basic core knowledge that you will need to know to move forward. Here's one tutorial: [The For Loop](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html).

Comment: Thanks - so far I have got most of the functionality to work. I'll edit the code to show what I have working.

But I have an issue where I can't set the size of the shapes that are printed.

Comment: Think I solved it, by adding a Radius Instance Variable in the DrawableCircle class & using it in the draw method in DrawableCircle - & then did similar with Height & Width in the DrawableRectangle.

Thanks for Your time & help though - much appreciated!